# Youtube downloader in python argv problem

Tags: python-3.x, argv

```
from sys import argv

link = argv[1]
yt = YouTube(link)

print("Title: ", yt.title)

print("View: ", yt.views)

yd = yt.streams.get_highest_resolution()

yd.download('./YTfolder')
```

here is mine code, can you guys look for this and help begginer?

here its my error :
File "/Users/dave/pythonn/yt_downloader.py", line 4, in 
link = argv[1]
IndexError: list index out of range

thanks guys!

Answer (score 1):

Command line arguments are those values that are passed during calling of program along with the calling statement. Thus, the first element of the array sys.argv() is the name of the program itself. sys.argv() is an array for command line arguments in Python. To employ this module named “sys” is used. sys.argv is similar to an array and the values are also retrieved like Python array.

Since **you are not passing any argument** when calling your program, you cannot iterate the 2nd element from argv array because it only have got one element.

```py
from sys import argv
print("Arguments are: "+str(argv))
```

Save as test.py. When you call the program like this.

```
> python3 test.py 1 2 3 4 5
Arguments are: ['test.py', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5']
```

Meanwhile if you call the program with no system arguments.

```
> python3 test.py
Arguments are: ['test.py']
```

If you are tryna build a CLI python program you might be interesed in **argparse** library.
https://www.golinuxcloud.com/python-argparse/